# How to access a file from the android project in Xamarin

Tags: c#, arrays, xamarin.android

I have two files in my android project in Xamarin which I would like to access and turn into a byte array. Something like:
`byte[] fileInBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine("Models", "myFile.dat"));`

[image: The two files that I would like at access]

But I haven't been able to access them with the methods I've tried so far. I've tried accessing them by using `assembly.GetName().Name + "." + "Models.myFile.dat")` but with no luck. I found a lot of examples on how to read from a file in the Assets folder, but I don't need to read, I need the file as bytes.

At the moment the files build action is set to "Embedded Resource", but I don't know if that is correct. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to access a file from the android project in Xamarin

**You should put your `myFile.dat` file into [Assets](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/) folder**, as the document said :

> Assets provide a way to include arbitrary files like text, xml, fonts, music, and video in your application. If you try to include these files as "resources", Android will process them into its resource system and you will not be able to get the raw data. If you want to access data untouched, Assets are one way to do it.

When you need get bytes from the file :

```
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("myFile.dat")))
{
     byte[] bytes = default(byte[]);
     using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         sr.BaseStream.CopyTo(memstream);
         bytes = memstream.ToArray();
     }
}
```

Comment: The solution worked fine.The only other thing I had to do was set the build action of the two files to "AndroidAsset"

Answer (score 0):

Add the read permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and every this will set to work.